# C# TableAdapter Configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have Pivot query in SQL Server 2012, when I fill query in Table Adapter Configuration Wizard (C#).
The message error appear

> 'The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported.

What should I do?

**SQL Query**

```
select *
from
(   
SELECT      [OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date],[OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code] as [JPCode], isnull(sum([OSG$Sales Line].Amount),0.00) as [Amount]    
FROM        [OSG$Sales Header] INNER JOIN
            [OSG$Sales Line] ON [OSG$Sales Header].No_ = [OSG$Sales Line].[Document No_] INNER JOIN
            OSG$Item ON [OSG$Sales Line].No_ = OSG$Item.No_ LEFT OUTER JOIN
            [OSG$End User] ON [OSG$Sales Header].[End User] = [OSG$End User].[End User Code]
WHERE       ([OSG$Sales Header].[Document Type] = 1) AND ([OSG$Sales Header].Status <> 0) AND ([OSG$Sales Header].[Close SO Reason] <> 1) AND 
            ([OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-03 00:00:00', 102)) 
            AND ([OSG$Sales Line].Quantity > 0) and [OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code] = '11' 
group by [OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date],[OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code] 

UNION ALL

SELECT       [OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date],[OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code] as [JPCode], isnull(sum([OSG$Sales Line].Amount),0.00) as [Amount]    
FROM        [OSG$Sales Header] INNER JOIN
            [OSG$Sales Line] ON [OSG$Sales Header].No_ = [OSG$Sales Line].[Document No_] INNER JOIN
            OSG$Item ON [OSG$Sales Line].No_ = OSG$Item.No_ LEFT OUTER JOIN
            [OSG$End User] ON [OSG$Sales Header].[End User] = [OSG$End User].[End User Code]
WHERE        ([OSG$Sales Header].[Document Type] = 1) AND ([OSG$Sales Header].Status <> 0) AND ([OSG$Sales Header].[Close SO Reason] <> 1) AND 
            ([OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'2015-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-04-03 00:00:00', 102)) 
            AND ([OSG$Sales Line].Quantity > 0) 
                         and [OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code] = '12'
group by  [OSG$Sales Header].[Order Date],[OSG$Item].[Global Dimension 2 Code]

) ThDailyOrdRcd 

pivot   (sum(Amount) for JPCode in([11],[12])) as pvt
```

**Output**

```
Order Date  |   11    |   12  |
2015-04-01  |914320   |333759 |
2015-04-02  |2137610  |153184 |
2015-04-03  |1461735  |74705  |
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to perform any kind of assistance. Please include more specifics about what you did that triggered the error.

Comment: For information check http://forums.asp.net/t/1317969.aspx?Pivot+in+SQL+Express